# Stick footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I need to set the footer at the bottom of the page. I changed the footers position from absolute, to fixed to relative, and it will either be sent high up the page or stay atop my aside element.

I have tried placing my footer in and outside my body element. This is unusual and not sure what else to do.

I am also open to other issues or bad style with my code.

```css
@charset "utf-8"
/* 
    Portfolio Project 1 
    
    HTML Styles 
    
    Author: John Smith
    Date: 4/10/2021 
    */

div.wrapDiv {
  width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
}

figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(204, 195, 151);
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

aside h2 {
  color: rgb(178, 102, 255);
  background-color: rgb(135, 206, 235);
}

aside.asideText {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-style: italic;
}

aside ul {
  list-style-type: square
}

section aside {
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

footer address {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-image: url(coffeelaptop.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 960px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(145, 153, 235);
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header a {
  color: rgba(138, 115, 156, 61);
}

header a:hover {
  color: rgba(216, 195, 232, 91)
}

header nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!--
Portfolio Project 1

Author: John Smith
Date: 4/10/2021
-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Web Designer for  Hire: John Smith">
  <meta name="keywords" content="WebDesign, JohnSmith, Website, Create, Design">

  <title>John Smith: Web Design Porfolio</title>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<body>
  <div id="wrapDiv">
    <a name="top"></a>
    <figure img>
      <a href="portfolio_resume.html"><img src="y9DpT.jpg" id="homePicture" alt="Place Holder" /></a>
    </figure>

    <header>
      <h1>John Smith - Web Designer</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="portfolio_home.html">Home</a> </li>
          <li><a href="portfolio_projects.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio_resume.html">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio_contacts.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section id=MainFocus>
      <article>
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <p>Hello, I John Smith and I am an aspiring Web Designer! I am working towards an associate degree for Software Development. I’d like to expand my skills and network with clients like you! We will make a great website together, at a Low Price!</p>

        <p>I was born and raised in [Redacted], [Redacted]. I was raised on computers since I was little. I am working on a two-year degree at Local Technical College, while attending free online classes. These classes range from codeacademy.com and freecodecamp.org.
          I am eager to learn more about software development and web design to be able to help people, from entrepreneur to big businesses be able to prosper! </p>

        <p>My dream is too improve my webdesign and software developer skills everyday. I believe webdesign is a great way working towards fullfilment as you help realize other peoples goals. Web Design simply put is my passion.</p>
      </article>

      <aside class="asideText">
        <h2>I am here for You!</h2>
        <p class="asideText">From business websites to vlogs I can make it for your business or personal needs!</p>
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Responsibility</strong>: I put forth qualtiy work and deliver them to my clients by the times they need!</li>
          <li><strong>Communication</strong> I will work with both my clients and other developers to deliver the best and most appropriate product possible.</li>
          <li><strong>Innovation</strong> I will not only give you what you need, but I will go the extra mile and try to make your website more effiencent and well designed!</li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    </section>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <address>Example Street 123 City, State Zip</address>
    <a href=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask>LinkedIn Profile
        </a>
    <br>
    <a href=example@gmail.com>Email Me</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#top">Back to top of page</a>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Many, many ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+footer+bottom+2021+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk020d0JNzP3flDvUxaOHpnKrKr9pGw:1618122117966&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinpa3QxvXvAhVH-yoKHbU4DLYQpwV6BAgBECQ&biw=2403&bih=1145)

Comment: Okay thank you. Did you take issue with the formatting of my question or the organizing or style of my code? I am very new to programming and web design, and its online community. Thank you for your help mplungjan.

Comment: Yes, too many words in the title and non-essential information makes it harder to quickly assess a question. Also some duplication of sentences after the code. Also remember to press TIDY before saving a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am looking for a the duplicated sentences after the code, but cannot find it yet. I see my question than my two snippets code. I will learn this site better over time to find. Also the link did not hit the mark. Their advice fixes the footer to the bottom of the users browser. I just want mine to sit at the bottom of the page, and not follow the user as they scroll... relative/absolute positioning? I am still googling the issue. Once again, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I removed the duplicate sentence and copied the rest above the snippet - there must be at least a hundred examples in the google link I posted that you can use